# QuickBooks Batchitem response in V3 QBO

Tags: c#, intuit-partner-platform

I am using V3 QBO. I am using Batch process to create invoice. i assign unique id in Bid field for every invoice item. After batch execution i need to store the status of invoice in to my table. Unfortunately the status is not updated in my tables. But the transactions were created successfully in QB Online. Is there any chance to fetch the status of invoice using the BId
again.

For QBD we have Ngid, using that id we can fetch the status anytime i am looking the way for QBO. Is there any solution for this problem. please help.

Answer (score 0):

In QBO, 'TxnStatus' attribute is not supported. So, it is not possible. So, it is not possible directly.

Ref - [QBO Invoice](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/030_entity_services_reference/invoice)

You can try to use the 'Balance' attribute which shows the unpaid amount. 
You can query an invoice by its id(getByID endponit) and check the 'Balance' status.

Thanks